# How to reset variables and rebuild DropDownList without using postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've had this issue for very long now where I am trying to get a user input from a person via a DropDownList. It seems to work the first time(after a postback). But when I try to get the user to select a new value from the DropDownList, it seems to default back to my previously selected values. My question is how do I get the javascript code to reassign the variables to the currently newly selected values. If I do a postback it seems to work since it gets refreshed. However I don't want to do a postback everytime.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function getCaseFiles(canMoveExpenses) {
        //create Popup with content from div
        $('#ddlFiles').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    debugger;
                    var dropDownList = document.getElementById("ddlCaseFilesNew");
                    var newCaseDdl = dropDownList.options[dropDownList.selectedIndex].value;
                    //alert("newCaseDdl = " + newCaseDdl);

                    var oldCaseFile = $("#hidCaseFile").val();//<asp:HiddenField id="hidCaseFile">
                    //alert(oldCaseFile);

                    if (newCaseDdl != -1) {
                        moveCasefile(canMoveExpenses, newCaseDdl, oldCaseFile);
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        $("#viewExpensesGrid").flexReload();
                    }
                    else {
                        showMessage("Error. Please Select a Value From The Lists.");
                    }
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    $("#viewExpensesGrid").flexReload();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and here is my DropDownList div:

```
<div id="ddlFiles">
    <label>
        Select new CaseFile:</label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFilesNew" DataSourceID="dsCaseFiles"
        DataTextField="Display" DataValueField="FileID" 
        OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" Width="300px"/>
</div>
```

My function calls this div and places it inside a custom popup.

Seems my variables containing the selectedIndex isn't being updates if it is not a postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an interesting mix of pure JS and jQuery code.
It seems that the problem is here:

```
var newCaseDdl = dropDownList.options[dropDownList.selectedIndex].value;
```

You save this value when `$(document).ready` is triggered.
Try this line instead:

```
var newCaseDdl = $("#ddlCaseFilesNew").val();
```

Be careful: if you use master-pages, ID of this element gonna look this: `ctl00$ddlCaseFilesNew`.
There are a couple of ways to avoid it: specify `name` or `class` attribute, and change selector: `$("[name=ddlCaseFilesNew]").val();` or `$(".ddlCaseFilesNew").val();`
The second one is to specify `ClientIDMode="Static"` on page or control.

Comment: I will try this quickly and let you know of the results. Thank you though for this information

Comment: would this work for the problems you listed : var dropDownList = document.getElementById$("#<%= ddlCaseFilesNew.ClientID %>");?